# Parsing M3U file

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to parse an m3u file but have hit a wall.

M3U file looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="6 eren" tvg-name="6'eren" tvg-logo="http://195.154.221.171/picons/6erendk.png" group-title="Denmark",6'eren
http://URL/something
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="6 eren" tvg-name="6'eren FHD" tvg-logo="http://195.154.221.171/picons/6erenhddk.png" group-title="Denmark",6'eren FHD
http://URL/something
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="6 eren" tvg-name="6'eren FHD" tvg-logo="http://195.154.221.171/picons/6erenhddk.png" group-title="Denmark",6'eren FHD
http://portal.siptveu.com:8080/8IsZPSZ7sc/IMd7O87LUj/9266
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="6'eren HD" group-title="Denmark",6'eren HD
http://URL/something
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Animal Planet" tvg-name="Animal Planet FHD" tvg-logo="http://195.154.221.171/picons/animalplanethddk.png" group-title="Denmark",Animal Planet FHD
http://URL/something
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Animal Planet" tvg-name="Animal Planet HD" tvg-logo="http://195.154.221.171/picons/animalplanethddk.png" group-title="Denmark",Animal Planet HD
http://URL/something
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="Boomerang" tvg-logo="http://195.154.221.171/picons/boomerangse.png" group-title="Denmark",Boomerang
http://URL/something
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="C More First FHD" group-title="Denmark",C More First FHD
http://URL/something
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="C More Hits FHD" group-title="Denmark",C More Hits FHD
http://URL/something

etc...
```

I need to get the value of tvg-name and the URL for the same entry.

So far I have created code to get the tvg-name which looks like this:

```
List<Channel> ChannelList = new List<Channel>();
                List<int> posOfTvgName = GetPositions(m3u, "tvg-name");

                var reg = new Regex("tvg-name=\".*?\"");
                var matches = reg.Matches(m3u);
                foreach (var item in matches)
                {
                    Channel c = new Channel();
                    string channelName = item.ToString();
                    channelName = item.ToString().Remove(0, 10);
                    channelName = channelName.Remove(channelName.Length - 1);
                    c.Name = channelName;

                    ChannelList.Add(c);
                }
```

But I've hit a bit of a snag as I don't know how to get the contents of the next line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try it like this `\btvg-name="([^"]+)".*\r?\n(https?\S+)` https://regex101.com/r/d3Onzy/1

Comment: ... and if you want to capture a third group (f.ex. if group-title is present), you can use this: \btvg-name="([^"]+)".*\r? \bgroup-title="([^"]+)".*\r?\n(https?\S+)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use 2 capturing groups and for the value of tvg-name use a negated character class matching any char except `"` instead of a non greedy `.*?`

The values are in group 1 and group 2 which are accessible using the [Match.Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?view=netframework-4.8) property.

If the next line should start with http and perhaps an optional s:

```
\btvg-name="([^"]+)".*\r?\n(https?\S+)
```

- `\btvg-name=` Match `tvg-name=` prepended with a word boundary
- `"([^"]+)"` Capture **group 1** between double quotes, match any char except `"`
- `.*\r?\n` Match any char except a newline 0+ times, then match a newline
- `(https?\S+)` Capture **group 2**, match http, optional s and 1+ times a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbtvg-name%3d%22%28%5b%5e%22%5d%2b%29%22.*%5cr%3f%5cn%28https%3f%5cS%2b%29&i=%23EXTM3U%0d%0a%23EXTINF%3a-1+tvg-id%3d%226+eren%22+tvg-name%3d%226%27eren%22+tvg-logo%3d%22http%3a%2f%2f195.154.221.171%2fpicons%2f6erendk.png%22+group-title%3d%22Denmark%22%2c6%27eren%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fURL%2fsomething%0d%0a%23EXTINF%3a-1+tvg-id%3d%226+eren%22+tvg-name%3d%226%27eren+FHD%22+tvg-logo%3d%22http%3a%2f%2f195.154.221.171%2fpicons%2f6erenhddk.png%22+group-title%3d%22Denmark%22%2c6%27eren+FHD%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fURL%2fsomething%0d%0a%23EXTINF%3a-1+tvg-id%3d%226+eren%22+tvg-name%3d%226%27eren+FHD%22+tvg-logo%3d%22http%3a%2f%2f195.154.221.171%2fpicons%2f6erenhddk.png%22+group-title%3d%22Denmark%22%2c6%27eren+FHD%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fportal.siptveu.com%3a8080%2f8IsZPSZ7sc%2fIMd7O87LUj%2f9266%0d%0a%23EXTINF%3a-1+tvg-name%3d%226%27eren+HD%22+group-title%3d%22Denmark%22%2c6%27eren+HD%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fURL%2fsomething%0d%0a%23EXTINF%3a-1+tvg-id%3d%22Animal+Planet%22+tvg-name%3d%22Animal+Planet+FHD%22+tvg-logo%3d%22http%3a%2f%2f195.154.221.171%2fpicons%2fanimalplanethddk.png%22+group-title%3d%22Denmark%22%2cAnimal+Planet+FHD%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fURL%2fsomething%0d%0a%23EXTINF%3a-1+tvg-id%3d%22Animal+Planet%22+tvg-name%3d%22Animal+Planet+HD%22+tvg-logo%3d%22http%3a%2f%2f195.154.221.171%2fpicons%2fanimalplanethddk.png%22+group-title%3d%22Denmark%22%2cAnimal+Planet+HD%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fURL%2fsomething%0d%0a%23EXTINF%3a-1+tvg-name%3d%22Boomerang%22+tvg-logo%3d%22http%3a%2f%2f195.154.221.171%2fpicons%2fboomerangse.png%22+group-title%3d%22Denmark%22%2cBoomerang%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fURL%2fsomething%0d%0a%23EXTINF%3a-1+tvg-name%3d%22C+More+First+FHD%22+group-title%3d%22Denmark%22%2cC+More+First+FHD%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fURL%2fsomething%0d%0a%23EXTINF%3a-1+tvg-name%3d%22C+More+Hits+FHD%22+group-title%3d%22Denmark%22%2cC+More+Hits+FHD%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fURL%2fsomething) | [C# Demo](https://ideone.com/PU7xn6)

An example how to get the values from the groups:

```
string pattern = @"\btvg-name=""([^""]+)"".*\r?\n(https?\S+)";
string input = @"#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id=""6 eren"" tvg-name=""6'eren"" tvg-logo=""http://195.154.221.171/picons/6erendk.png"" group-title=""Denmark"",6'eren
http://URL/something ...";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine("tvg-name: {0} URL: {1}" , m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Comment: @Martin Please mark this solution as the answer if indeed it is.

Comment: How can I add group-title and tvg-logo ?

Comment: @Web.11 If the order is the same of the properties, you could for example use optional non capture groups with a capture group inside it. See https://regex101.com/r/9xyETO/1